# Django rest framework serialize a dictionary

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

Hi everyone I am using Django rest framework, and I want to serialize a dictionary object that I obtain when I consult a database

```
  def retrieve(self, request, project_name=None):
    try:
      opc = {'name_proj' : project_name }
      alldata = connect_database(opc)
    except KeyError:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    except ValueError:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    serializer = serializers.cpuProjectsSerializer(instance=alldata, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

when I call to `connect_database(opc)` function, I consult the database and return all the rows.

after that a create, a dictionary obj that I return in `alldata`, so I call to my serializers method with a dictionary.

my dictionary object is like that

```
{names:['example'], example:{jobs_running:[[], [],[] ]}, {jobs_pending:[[],[],[]] }}
```

Real data is like this

```
{'names': [u'ad'], u'ad': {
'jobs_running': [[1459861201000, 0L], [1459864801000, 0L], [1459868401000, 0L], [1459872001000, 0L], [1459875601000, 0L], [1459879201000, 0L], [1459882801000, 0L], [1459886401000, 0L]], 
'jobs_pending': [[1459861201000, 0L], [1459864801000, 0L], [1459868401000, 0L], [1459872001000, 0L], [1459875601000, 0L], [1459879201000, 0L], [1459882801000, 0L], [1459886401000, 0L]] }
}
```

My problem is that I don't know how to create a serializer file.

I try this, return a name  like string, jobs_running and jobs_pendding like a dictionary

```
class cpuProjectsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
  project = serializers.CharField(max_length=256)
  jobs_running = serializers.DictField()
  jobs_pending = serializers.DictField()


  def create(self, validated_data):
    """
    Create and return a new `cpuProjects` instance, given the validated data.
    """
    return cpuProjects.objects.create(**validated_data)

  def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    """
    Update and return an existing `cpuProjects` instance, given the validated data.
    """
    instance.project = validated_data.get('names', instance.project)
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

but I receive this error

```
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `tuple` instance.
Original exception text was: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'project'.
```

Any idea how to return this datas

thanks in advance!

Comment: `{names:[], {jobs_running:[[], [],[] ]}, {jobs_pending:[[],[],[]] }}` is not a valid `dict`. If you made an error, update an answer.

Comment: Thanks @vishes_shell I correct the dict!

Comment: @vishes_shell I expect something like that https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?

Comment: I'm sorry, `0L` is `str` object?

Comment: In my case is a int @vishes_shell

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `instance` is `Tuple[ProjectModel, bool]` not `Project`
That's why you can got the error. The implementation is supposed to be like this

```
from typing import Tuple

def update(self, instance: Tuple[ProjectModel, bool] , validated_data):
    instance[0].project = validated_data.get('names', instance.project)
    instance[0].save()
    return instance
```